# How to change color click on button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to change background color when I click on edit button.Its working but when I click first time in edit button then first row highlighted.second time I click on anther edit button then second row highlighted.I want to when I click on any edit button only this row highlighted. So how can I do it?

```
    $('.edit_btn').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.field_name').prop('contenteditable', true);
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.field_name').css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
```

I was attached my structure in image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5qA7.png)

```
<form method="post" action="" name="city_list">
    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" border="1" style="width:100%" class=""> 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Action</th> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="field_id">1</td>
                <td class="field_name" style="background-color: yellow;">mumbai</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit_btn" name="edit"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="save" class="save_btn" name="save_btn"></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="field_id">2</td>
                <td contenteditable="true" class="field_name" style="background-color: yellow;">pune</td>
                <td><input type="button" value="edit" class="edit_btn" name="edit"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="save" class="save_btn" name="save_btn"></td>  
            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: can u pls provide the fiddle so that we can help you

Comment: You could have an array and push the selected rows into it. OR you could look into two way data binding like in angular for example.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing your markup?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.edit_btn').click(function () {
    //remove other highlighted fields
    $('table').find('.field_name').css('background', 'none')
    //add highlight to this row
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field_name').css("background", "yellow");
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/874g7uvz/

Comment: @user318941 I updated the code. try again with new code.

Answer (score 0):

in css create class

```
.yellowBg {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

edit js

```
$('.edit_btn').click(function () {
    $('.yellowbg').removeClass('yellowBg');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.field_name').addClass('yellowBg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".edit_btn").on("click",function(){

        $("td").removeClass("highlight");

        $(this).closest("tr").find(".field_name").addClass("highlight");

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .highlight {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr><td>1</td><td class="field_name">Taghdisi</td><td><button class="edit_btn">Edit</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td class="field_name">Azadi</td><td><button class="edit_btn">Edit</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td class="field_name">Kazemi</td><td><button class="edit_btn">Edit</button></td></tr>
        </table>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".edit_btn").on("click",function(){

                $("td").removeClass("highlight");

                $(this).closest("tr").find(".field_name").addClass("highlight");

            })

        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user318941 , check my answer!

Comment: Thank you so much @ehsan :) :)